# How to make a frameless atom?

Tags: css, sass, atom-editor

I found the following post on Atom forum, there are scripts of re-writing the UI of Atom.

The question is, where am I supposed to put the script? In Atom init script? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

Answer (score 1):

`npm -g install asar` exstract *`atom.app/resources/app.asar`* add `frame: false,` after `title: 'Atom',` in *`atom-window.coffee`* delete *`app.asar`* then pack again.

exstract: `asar e app.asar a`

pack: `asar p a app.asar`

see also https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4599

https://github.com/electron/asar

Answer (score 0):

#### Add this to your Atom Config (From Atom menu, select Config):

```coffeescript
core:
  useCustomTitleBar: true
```

#### Append this to your Atom Style (From Atom menu, select Stylesheet):

```sass
// Hide title
.title-bar .title {
  display: none;
}

// Remove background from titlebar and toolbars
.title-bar,
.tool-bar,
.tool-bar button.tool-bar-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
}

// Shift the tabs up
atom-workspace atom-workspace-axis.horizontal {
  // NOTE: comment this out if you want draggable titlebar:
  margin-top: -20px;
}

// Keep the side panels aligned
atom-panel-container{
  &.left {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  &.right {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

.fullscreen {
  atom-workspace atom-workspace-axis.horizontal {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  atom-panel-container{
    &.left {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    &.right {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

atom-workspace atom-panel-container.left:empty + atom-workspace-axis.vertical .tab-bar {
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

[For more information see here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4599)